# What Type of Hierarchy is Responsible for this Style of Onboarding?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I see many applications that display onboarding view controllers before allowing access to the main content. I have noticed that a lot of the onboarding tutorials initially display the onboarding content and then dismiss that view controller to allow access to the content.

I know that Xcode gives warnings when you try to present a view controller on a view that is not visible, such as in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear:`. So instantiating the content's view controller inside of a navigation controller, and then trying to present the onboarding view controller seemingly only works without errors if it's presented in `viewDidAppear:`. However, in the applications that I am referencing, the onboarding is the initially visible view before it gets dismissed to allow access to the application's content.

So what type of hierarchy allows this type of transition between view controllers when navigation controllers are presenting the onboarding without seeing the application's content prior to `viewDidAppear:` being called?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm working on an onboarding screen myself and cannot find a 'clean' way to do it.

Comment: I typically just build my view controllers, and then present the onboarding in `viewDidAppear:` of the first view controller. It seems to be the quickest way without custom view controller transitions or hacks.

Comment: Great thanks! Do you use the `present()` method or segue?

Comment: I use `present:animated:completion` because I don’t use storyboards. Also, if you need to obscure the app’s content before presenting an onboarding, you can put a view on the initial view controller that covers the screen, having it be shown as the onboarding is presented, which will allow the user to view the onboarding while not being able to see the app’s content until dismissed. To achieve this, I just put a view over my initial view controller’s content, make it match my launch screen, and then present the onboarding after the initial view controller (with the obscuring view) appears.

Comment: That’s great - I’m going to try it. Thanks.