# Graphical artefact on navigation bar and toolbar when presenting UIPageViewController modally over a UITableViewController

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

My app is simply a `UITableViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. In the main tableview controller `viewDidLoad()` method I check `UserDefaults` for a Boolean key to see if it is the first startup. If so, I modally present a `UIPageViewController` for a tutorial and onboarding.

```
self.present(tutorialViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, underneath the tutorial screens, my main view controller’s `navigationBar` and `toolBar` change to a light grey colour until the tableview is interacted with, then they instantly change back to the default translucent appearance that I want. I cannot figure out what is causing this. I tried setting `modalPresentationStyle` to `.overCurrentContext` but this did not help.

I also get a warning that presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged. This warning goes away if I present it as follows:

```
self.parent?.present(tutorialViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This seems messy however, and the graphical artefact remains.

Am I presenting the `tutorialViewController` from the wrong place or in the wrong way? The tutorial screens seem to work as expected - it’s just the underlying navigation bar and toolbar briefly have the wrong colour. I need to present it over the tableview as the last page of the tutorial is transparent with a blur effect to help see how the app works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution based on some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44231639/8289095).

I was presenting the modal view controller from the `viewDidLoad()` method when I should have done it in `viewDidAppear()`.

I was also animating my tableview to fade in, so it was not visible before the tutorial screens. Instead, I’m now using a blocking view set to the same background colour as my tutorial view controller. In `viewDidLoad()` I do this:

```
let blockingView = UIView()
blockingView.frame = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.frame
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(blockingView)
```

This means the blocking view appears in front of the navigation controller. I fade and remove the `blockingView` just before presenting the tutorial in `viewDidAppear()`.